# Importing some libraries in Python fails

Tags: python, windows, error-handling, path, permissions

I do not know what happened, but suddenly I can no longer run Python code like before. I am on windows and I have a feeling the problem is the result of PATH, because I have seen this error before.

Python gives me the following error when trying to import matplotlib:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'axes' from 'matplotlib' 
(C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Packages
\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\
Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py)
```

When trying to install matplotlib, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5]
Toegang geweigerd: 'C:\\Users\\JohnDoe\\AppData\\Local\\Packages
\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages
\\Python310\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\ft2font.cp310-win_amd64.pyd'
Check the permissions.
```

My setup:

- Windows 11
- VS Code installed through the MS Store
- Python installed through VS Code, which also installs python through the MS Store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue. For future reference, the solution was:

- Run `pip list`, take note of every package starting with ~ and where the first letter is missing (example `~atplotlib` instead of `matplotlib`). The location of the directory is also shown.
- Open the location as indicated by `pip list` in a file explorer, find the package starting with a ~ and delete the folder.
- The command `pip install matplotlib` and `pip install --user matplotlib` still create a `OSerror` stating the permission is denied. This error occurs both in the terminal of VS Code, command prompt and command prompt opened as administrator.
- The solution to the `OSerror` is to run VS Code as administrator and then run `pip install matplotlib` from the terminal in VS Code.

To summarize: delete the conflicting package and reinstall through the VS Code terminal while running VS Code as administrator.

All other suggestions I found online to solve this issue failed for me. These suggestions included changing the permission in windows to full access.